# Jquery and CSS Z-index

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I've been roaming through the forum for some answers to this problem, but none have seemed to fit my code.
I'm using an Awkward Gallery Slider and a fixed header. And the problem is the fixed header gets behind the slider just after it loads the next image.

I've managed to use a Z-index attribute to the header which gets the header in front for about 2 seconds, which is much probably related to the auto load of the next image.
Begginer here, so any help is appreciated. :-)

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#showcase").awShowcase(
 {
  content_width:   700,
  content_height:   470,
  fit_to_parent:   false,
  auto:     true,
  interval:    3000,
  continuous:    false,
  loading:    true,
  tooltip_width:   200,
  tooltip_icon_width:  32,
  tooltip_icon_height: 32,
  tooltip_offsetx:  18,
  tooltip_offsety:  0,
  arrows:     true,
  buttons:    true,
  btn_numbers:   true,
  keybord_keys:   true,
  mousetrace:    false, /* Trace x and y coordinates for the mouse */
  pauseonover:   true,
  stoponclick:   false,
  transition:    'hslide', /* hslide/vslide/fade */
  transition_delay:  0,
  transition_speed:  500,
  show_caption:   'onload', /* onload/onhover/show */
  thumbnails:    false,
  thumbnails_position: 'outside-last', /* outside-last/outside-first/inside-last/inside-first */
  thumbnails_direction: 'vertical', /* vertical/horizontal */
  thumbnails_slidex:  1, /* 0 = auto / 1 = slide one thumbnail / 2 = slide two thumbnails / etc. */
  dynamic_height:   false, /* For dynamic height to work in webkit you need to set the width and height of images in the source. Usually works to only set the dimension of the first slide in the showcase. */
  speed_change:   true, /* Set to true to prevent users from swithing more then one slide at once. */
  viewline:    false, /* If set to true content_width, thumbnails, transition and dynamic_height will be disabled. As for dynamic height you need to set the width and height of images in the source. */
  custom_function:  null /* Define a custom function that runs on content change */
 });
});
```

```css
.header-cont {
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 width:100% 
 z-index:100;
}

.header {
 height:250px;
 width:100%;
 background:url(../images/banner1.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 margin:0px auto;
 opacity:0.8;
 filter:alpha(opacity=80);
 -moz-opacity:0.8;
 -khtml-opacity:0.8;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
 box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
 text-align:center;
 z-index:100;
}

body
{
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

a
{
 color: #ff377c;
}

p
{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h1
{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

h2
{
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.menu
{
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #999;
}

 .menu a
 {
  color: #999;
 }
 
 .menu a.active
 {
  font-weight: bold;
 }


/* Showcase
-------------*/

#awOnePageButton .view-slide
{
 display: none;
}

/* This class is removed after the showcase is loaded */
/* Assign the correct showcase height to prevent loading jumps in IE */
.showcase-load
{
 height: 470px; /* Same as showcase javascript option */
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* Container when content is shown as one page */
.showcase-onepage
{
 /**/
}

/* Container when content is shown in slider */
.showcase
{
 position: relative;
 top:400px;
 margin: auto;
 z-index:0;
}

 .showcase-content-container
 {
  background-color: #000;
  z-index:0;
 }
 
 /* Navigation arrows */
 .showcase-arrow-previous, .showcase-arrow-next
 {
  position: absolute;
  background: url('../images/arrows.png');
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  top: 220px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .showcase-arrow-previous
 {
  left: -60px;
 }
 
 .showcase-arrow-previous:hover
 {
  background-position: 0px -34px;
 }
 
 .showcase-arrow-next
 {
  right: -56px;
  background-position: -34px 0;
 }
 
 .showcase-arrow-next:hover
 {
  background-position: -34px -34px;
 }
 
 /* Content */
 .showcase-content
 {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:0;
 }
  
  .showcase-content-wrapper
  {
   text-align: center;
   height: 470px;
   width: 700px;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   z-index:0;
  }
  
  /* Styling the tooltips */
  .showcase-plus-anchor
  {
   background-image: url('../images/plus.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  
  .showcase-plus-anchor:hover
  {
   background-position: -32px 0;
  }
  
  div.showcase-tooltip
  {
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #000;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 5px 8px;
   background-image: url(../images/white-opacity-80.png);
  }
  
  /* Styling the caption */
  .showcase-caption
  {
   color: #000;
   padding: 8px 15px;
   text-align: left;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px;
   display: none;
   background-image: url(../images/white-opacity-80.png);
  }
  
 .showcase-onepage .showcase-content
 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 
 /* Button Wrapper */
 .showcase-button-wrapper
 {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
  .showcase-button-wrapper span
  {
   margin-right: 3px;
   padding: 2px 5px 0px 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #444444;
  }
 
  .showcase-button-wrapper span.active
  {
   color: #fff;
  }
 
 /* Thumbnails */
 .showcase-thumbnail-container /* Used for backgrounds, no other styling!!! */
 {
  background-color: #000;
 }
 
 .showcase-thumbnail-wrapper
 {
  overflow: hidden;
 }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail
  {
   width: 120px;
   height: 90px;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: solid 1px #333;
   position: relative;
  }
  
   .showcase-thumbnail-caption
   {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
   }
   
   .showcase-thumbnail-content
   {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
   }
   
   .showcase-thumbnail-cover
   {
    background-image: url(../images/black-opacity-40.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
   }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail:hover
  {
   border: solid 1px #999;
  }
  
   .showcase-thumbnail:hover .showcase-thumbnail-cover
   {
    display: none;
   }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail.active
  {
   border: solid 1px #999;
  }
  
   .showcase-thumbnail.active .showcase-thumbnail-cover
   {
    display: none;
   }
 
 .showcase-thumbnail-wrapper-horizontal
 {
  padding: 10px;
 }
 
  .showcase-thumbnail-wrapper-horizontal .showcase-thumbnail
  {
   margin-right: 10px;
   width: 116px;
  }
 
 .showcase-thumbnail-wrapper-vertical
 {
  padding: 10px;
 }
 
  .showcase-thumbnail-wrapper-vertical .showcase-thumbnail
  {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
 .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward,
 .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward
 {
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward
 {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
 }
 
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward .showcase-thumbnail-vertical,
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward .showcase-thumbnail-vertical,
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward .showcase-thumbnail-horizontal,
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward .showcase-thumbnail-horizontal
  {
   background-image: url(../images/arrows-small.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 17px;
   height: 17px;
  }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward .showcase-thumbnail-vertical
  {
   background-position: 0 -51px;
   margin-left: 55px;
  }
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward:hover .showcase-thumbnail-vertical
  {
   background-position: -17px -51px;
  }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward .showcase-thumbnail-vertical
  {
   background-position: 0 -34px;
   margin-left: 55px;
  }
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward:hover .showcase-thumbnail-vertical
  {
   background-position: -17px -34px;
  }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward .showcase-thumbnail-horizontal
  {
   background-position: 0 -17px;
   margin-top: 40px;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward:hover .showcase-thumbnail-horizontal
  {
   background-position: -17px -17px;
  }
  
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward .showcase-thumbnail-horizontal
  {
   background-position: 0 0;
   margin-top: 40px;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward:hover .showcase-thumbnail-horizontal
  {
   background-position: -17px 0;
  }
  
  /* Hide button text */
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-forward span span,
  .showcase-thumbnail-button-backward span span
  {
   display: none;
  }
 

.clear
{
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-cont">
 <div class="header">
     <div id="header-text">CLINICAS | PROGRAMAS | MARCACOES | URGÊNCIA 
        </div>
  </div>
      </div>



<div style="width: 700px; margin: auto;">

  <div id="showcase" class="showcase">
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <!-- If the slide contains multiple elements you should wrap them in a div with the class .showcase-content-wrapper. 
    We usually wrap even if there is only one element, because it looks better. :-) -->
    <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
     <h1>Start.</h1>
     <h2>Creativity.</h2>
     <p>Logic.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="01" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="03" />
   </div>
   <!-- Put the caption content in a div with the class .showcase-caption -->
   <div class="showcase-caption">
    It's a flying wasp. <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/14516334@N00/345009210/"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
  
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="02" />
   </div>
   <!-- Put the tooltips in a div with the class .showcase-tooltips. -->
   <div class="showcase-tooltips">
    <!-- Each anchor in .showcase-tooltips represents a tooltip. The coords attribute represents the position of the tooltip. -->
    <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="634,130">
     <!-- The content of the anchor-tag is displayed in the tooltip. -->
     
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="200,440">
     
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="600,440">
     
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="356, 172">
     <!-- You can add multiple elements to the anchor-tag which are displayed in the tooltip. -->
     <img src="images/glasses.png" />
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
     <h1>Simplicity</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/1185346?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="700" height="470" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
   <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
   <div class="showcase-content">
    <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
     <h1>Hospital do Elefante</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this design](http://jsfiddle.net/Navelpluisje/xpgzP/), where there is a fixed header. The issue with your is that your scroll bar spans the header as well.

Comment: Check out this query plug in which allows you to keep the header at the very top of the z-index stack by calculating it using query. https://code.google.com/p/topzindex/